# How to plot a Gantt chart using timesteps and not dates using plotly

Tags: python

So I found this code online that would make a Gantt chart:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource="Max")
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.show()
```

However, I wish to not use date and times but rather use timesteps, starting from 0 nanoseconds and so forth, what I would want is something that would look like this:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start=0, Finish=10, Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start=12, Finish=24, Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start=5, Finish=20, Resource="Max")
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.show()
```

Is this something that would be possible using plotly or does it only use Date and time? I want to use plotly because it gives a very clean graph.

I've looked in the plotly express documentation but found nothing to convert and use timesteps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `plotly.figure_factory` gantt chart and forcing the x-axis to show numbers. There are few examples [here](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.figure_factory.create_gantt.html), if you need to know more about this. The code output is as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start=0, Finish=10, Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start=12, Finish=24, Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start=5, Finish=20, Resource="Max")
])

fig = ff.create_gantt(df, index_col = 'Resource',  bar_width = 0.4, show_colorbar=True)
fig.update_layout(xaxis_type='linear', autosize=False, width=800, height=400)
fig.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Plotly Gantt charts only work with dates, but a possible workaround is to add the date 1970-01-01 to the beginning of all of the times, then display the times (in this case, seconds) without displaying the date in your plot.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
dict(Task="Job A", Start='1970-01-01 00:00:00', Finish='1970-01-01 00:00:10', Resource="Alex"),
dict(Task="Job B", Start='1970-01-01 00:00:12', Finish='1970-01-01 00:00:24', Resource="Alex"),
dict(Task="Job C", Start='1970-01-01 00:00:05', Finish='1970-01-01 00:00:20', Resource="Max")
])
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", 
color="Resource")

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(
                  title='Timestamp', 
                  tickformat = '%S'))
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.show()
```

Comment: I thought about doing this however the conversion could get quite tricky as soon as we pass 60 seconds and 60 minutes and 24 hours

Comment: Ohhhh yeah, I agree, then use the method as mentioned by Redox.

Comment: You can solve this by converting your times into datetimes first: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(secs)` and using `tickformat="%s"`