# Looking for a way to visualize sequence data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

Suppose I have a Pandas dataframe which looks as follow:

| Event Type | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| B | 2.5 | 5 |
| C | 9.5 | 11 |
| A | 6 | 9 |

I want to draw it as like:

[image: demo viz]

Note that it is possible for events of the same type to overlap each other.

What package and how can it be done in Python?

Comment: How do you order the events? Alphabatical?

Comment: @Krishna can be, the order is not particularly important.

Comment: You can checkout `plotly`. Here are some pointers that may help you [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73247210/how-to-plot-a-gantt-chart-using-timesteps-and-not-dates-using-plotly), [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63714679/plotting-gantt-chart-using-timestamps), [Link](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using matplotlib and pandas library of python

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    'Event Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    'Start Time': [1, 2.5, 9.5, 6, 2, 4, 8],
    'End Time': [3, 5, 11, 9, 4, 6, 10]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Start Time'] = [datetime.now().replace(hour=int(t)) for t in df['Start Time']]
df['End Time'] = [datetime.now().replace(hour=int(t)) for t in df['End Time']]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

event_types = df['Event Type'].unique()
event_type_y = {event_type: i for i, event_type in enumerate(event_types)}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    y = event_type_y[row['Event Type']]
    ax.fill_betweenx([y, y + 1], row['Start Time'], row['End Time'], label=row['Event Type'], alpha=0.5)

ax.set_xlim(min(df['Start Time']), max(df['End Time']))
ax.set_yticks(range(len(event_types)))
ax.set_yticklabels(event_types)
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks @Mahboob. Is there a way to make each event shown as multiple levels on the y-axis? In my dataset there can be a lot of different types of events burst within a short period so it can be hard to tell which events happened.

Comment: Sure, I have modify the code for you . You can see the output in the image too.

Answer (score 2):

A possible option using [`barh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.barh.html) :

```
colors = {"A": "red", "B": "green", "C": "yellow"}

df["Width"] = df["End Time"].sub(df["Start Time"])
df["Color"] = df["Event Type"].map(colors)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 3), tight_layout=True)

ax.barh(y="Event Type", width="Width", left="Start Time",
        color="Color", data=df, ec="black")

ax.set(xlabel="Time", ylabel="Event",
       xticks=np.insert(np.arange(1, df["End Time"].max()+1, 2), 0, 0))

plt.show();
```

And if you want to have an axis line arrow-styles, you can add these lines before the show :

```
# to make the axis line styles 
ax.set_ylim(bottom=-0.5); ax.set_xlim(left=0)
ax.spines[["top", "right"]].set_visible(False)
ax.plot(0,1,"^k", mew=3, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)
ax.plot(1,-0.5,">k", mew=3, transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, code looks clean. Sadly I cannot mark both posts as answer but appreciate it.